# taskbar popup menu in java

Tags: java, swing, popup, taskbar

how to create a pop up when write clicked on the application icon in the taskbar .
eg: on rightclicking the outlook 2013 . popup menu having Tasks such as

1. New-Email message
2. New Appointment
3. New meeting
4. New contact
5. New task

appears. How can this be achieved in Java (using swing).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are referring to the System Tray in Java, have a look at this tutorial provided by Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html.

Comment: actually in windows 8 when u right click on some application icon present in the task bar there are options such as close all and standard close option but for some application such as the Eclipse.there are more option such as "new task" , "activate task". thats what i want to add in my application.but thank you for ur response. for more eg. when google chrome icon is right clicked the pop up contains Most visited pages.

Comment: like this [link](http://res1.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows%207/main/1f30611e-483a-4e88-a875-10ca38f9f8a2_24.jpg)

Comment: Based on your description of the problem, I really thought you were referring to what's called the system tray in Java. Now, that I understand what you are really after... I don't think it can be done in Swing, you do refer that Eclipse uses it but keep in mind that Eclipse doesn't use Swing, it uses SWT.

Answer (score 0):

*This is for the future viewers of this question.*

What you're actually referring to, is the so called Windows API Code Pack feature, *JumperList*, here's a [blog post](https://www.developer.com/microsoft/creating-windows-7-jump-lists-with-the-api-code-pack-and-visual-studio-2008/) that shows you how you can use it in a .NET Program, created in *C#* I believe.

This feature is supported by *Windows 7 SP1+*.

There are no *(as far as I know)* new libraries that support jumplists in a native-like way. However, you can use J7Goodies to get a work-around.

***J7Goodies-Example by me***

```java
public static void main(final String... args) {
        if (!(System.getProperty("os.name").matches("Windows\\s(7|8(\\.1)?|10|11)")))
            System.err.println("The Taskbar API is not supported on this operating system!");
        
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JumperListDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        final JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("Item 1");
        final JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("Item 2");
        popup.add(item1);
        popup.add(item2);
        
        item1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Action invoked (1)");
            }
        });
        
        item2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Action invoked (2)");
            }
        });
        
        
        final JumpList jumpList = new JumpList();
        final DestinationList tasks = new DestinationList();
        tasks.addTask("Path", "", "Text", "Path", 0, "Description");;
        
        jumpList.appendTasks(tasks);
        jumpList.save();
        
}
```

*You'll need the latest J7Goodies.jar to run this file!*